# How do I do this with string in Java?

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have a string that holds `“LANNISTERS”,` and I want a new string to hold just the `“AR”` characters which are the second letter, and second to last letter, how do I do that? Because substring will grab everything in between, and I can’t char, since char is incompatible with string, Thank You!!!

I have this:

```
String in = "LANNISTERS";
int getter1 = in.charAt(1);
int getter2 = in.charAt(in.length() - 1);
String s = in.substring(getter1, getter1 + 1) + in.substring(getter2, getter2 + 1);
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: `char` is incompatible with `String`, but you can always convert a `char` to a `String` using [`Character.toString(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString(char)) (or `"" + ch`).

Comment: How would like to handle the edge case of a string string which has less than 4 characters?

Comment: With the updated question and the sample code, you can't use a `char` value (`getter1`) to *index* a string. Just index directly: `in.substring(1, 2) + in.substring(len - 2, len - 1)`. This will return weird result or fail, if you don't consider the comment by @TimBiegeleisen.

Comment: Do you need to handle strings containing surrogates, like ``?

Comment: The answer would clearly depend on whether he is vegetarian.  And I did not know SO had emoticons.

Comment: @AndyTurner Introducing code points to a newbie like this is just mean, man. ;-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it doesn't - it is just [this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f355/index.htm).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Those are unicode 1F355 [SLICE OF PIZZA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F355/index.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and either [`String.charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) (or [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) to convert the `String` to a `char[]`). Something like,

```
String in = "LANNISTERS";
char[] chars = in.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2);
sb.append(chars[1]).append(chars[chars.length - 2]);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**or** from [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) comment below, as a one liner like

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[] { in.charAt(1)
        , in.charAt(in.length() - 2) }));
```

**or** the same thing with a `StringBuilder`

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(in.charAt(1))
        .append(in.charAt(in.length() - 2)));
```

whichever you prefer.

Comment: Is there any particular advantage in the `toCharArray()` call, rather than just using `in.charAt(1)` and `in.charAt(in.length() - 2)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I (personally) think it makes the code easier to read, but that's subjective. Of course, readability is a particular advantage.

Comment: How about a simple one-liner? `new String(new char[] { in.charAt(1), in.charAt(in.length() - 2) })`. No need for the overhead of copying the string into an array or the overhead of `StringBuilder`. --- I do agree with @AndyTurner that `charAt()` seems a better choice for this question, but that's just my opinion. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex:

```
String s = in.replaceAll("(?:.(.).*(.).)?", "$1$2");
```

The regex captures the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup>-last characters as groups 1 ans 2 respectively while the entire input is matched. The replacement then puts just groups 1 and 2 back.

If the input is too short to have (separate) matched groups, the resulting string is a blank, thanks to the entire expression being optional, which will always match.